# Snowflake -Pyspark numPartitions support

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're attempting to run the snowflake query with Pyspark, and we've set numPartitions to 10 and submitted a spark query. However, when I checked the Snowflake History tab. As far as I can tell, only one query is being executed rather than ten.

Is the numPartitions clause supported by snowflake -Spark? The sample code we used to execute is shown below.

```
sfOptions = dict()
sfOptions["url"] ="jdbc:snowflake://**************.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com"
sfOptions["user"] ="**01d"
sfOptions["private_key_file"] = key_file
sfOptions["private_key_file_pwd"] = key_passphrase
sfOptions["db"] ="**_DB"
sfOptions["warehouse"] ="****_WHS"
sfOptions["schema"] ="***_SHR"
sfOptions["role"] ="**_ROLE"
sfOptions["numPartitions"]="10"
sfOptions["partitionColumn"] = "***_TRANS_ID"
sfOptions["lowerBound"] = lowerbound
sfOptions["upperBound"] = upperbound

print(sfOptions)

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("query", "select * from ***_shr.SPRK_TST as f") \
    .load()
```

Need your help and guidance one this . Thanks!

Comment: Hi - have you read the Snowflake documentation that  lists the supported options?

Comment: Going by the following blog detail, the value seems to be a supported one : https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2021/09/07/execute-queries-in-parallel-against-snowflake-using-aws-glue/

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `sfOptions["numPartitions"] = 10`

Comment: It looks like snowflake doesn't have support for this... All they have is partition size but num partition and partitionColumn does not work

Comment: No such option: [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#:~:text=partition_size_in_mb)